# Error "Index was out of range" in ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, indexing, range

I am making an application ASP.Net / C # where I have a Gridview with checkbox in each row.

The problem is that some of them by selecting and clicking the "Save" the following error occurs:

**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. \ r \ nParameter name: index.**

And this error seems to be occurring only in the last row of the Gridview. The follow is the snippet of code and properties window Gridview:

**C#**

```
protected void btnOKVulsProj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            //Variables

        for (int cont = 0; cont < grdListaVulsProj.Rows.Count; cont++)
        {
            idVul = Convert.ToInt32((grdListaVulsProj.Rows[cont].Cells[0]).Text);

            string strQueryInsert = ("INSERT TO DATABASE");

            if (((CheckBox)grdListaVulsProj.Rows[idVul].FindControl("chkSelecionaItem")).Checked)  <<< WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS

            {
                Conexao.Inserir(strQueryInsert); //Method that performs the insertion
            }
        };

            //Other instructions

    }
```

**Gridview Properties's**

http://i56.tinypic.com/33f3hqf.jpg

Note: Gridview aims to register on the database all rows that are selected.

Note2: I searched extensively for a Web solution, but all presented, none of them solved my problem.

Thank you!

[ ]'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your line should be:

```
if (((CheckBox)grdListaVulsProj.Rows[cont].FindControl("chkSelecionaItem")).Checked)  <<< WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
```

Comment: This really makes a lot more sense

Comment: Thank you very much fantasticfix. This solved my problem. A simple logic error, perhaps because I am beginner :P

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess your problem is here:

```
if (((CheckBox)grdListaVulsProj.Rows[idVul]...
```

Is `idVul` really the index into the rows collection, or did you mean to use `cont` there?

Comment: I thought that was the right way, but the one above makes more sense. (y)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I usually run into is that row 0 is actually the header and the last row is the footer.

Try a compare like this:

```
if (grdListaVulsProj.Rows[cont].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
// your code here
}
```

Comment: Unaware of this form, then I'll test it too.  Thaks for reply